# How to get R's variable name in C (substitute in C)?

Tags: r, c

How can I get from C an object name used as a function argument? I
have sample code in C that gives me access to the name of the function
being called:

```
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP xname(SEXP x)
{
       const char *fun_name = CHAR(PRINTNAME(CAR(x)));
       x =  CDR(x);
       const char *arg_name = isNull(TAG(x)) ? "" : CHAR(PRINTNAME(TAG(x)));

       Rprintf("fn_name: %s, arg_name: %s\n", fun_name, arg_name);
       return R_NilValue;
}
```

and from R:

```
> xname <- function(...) invisible(.External("xname", ...))
> x1 = 123
> xname(x1)
fn_name: xname, var_name:
```

However, I am trying to find a way to access the object name. In the
documentation I found a solution for named args only:

```
> xname(arg = x1)
fn_name: xname, var_name: arg
```

And I'd like to find the C equivalent for `substitute()`:

```
> substitute(x1)
x1
```

I tried `substitute()` from `Rinternals.h`, but it always returned a list with what above. Does anyone know how to do it? Maybe `findVarInFrame()`?

Best regards

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I want to know the name of the R object that was given as a function argument. In my example, you have xname(), which calls the target function written in C (.External('xname')). My example allows to specify the name of the function that called .External() and if we have a named arg, then also the name of that argument. If you want to write custom merge() in C to make it fast, sometimes you will have to generate column names, e.g. c ('X.C1', 'Y.C1'), and for that you need to know the name of objects X and Y. When you call C function you don't pass the name of the object, but the pointer to it.